# Why does this give me error: 80040154

Tags: c#, excel

I am using this code to read an Excel spreadsheet:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace myProject
{
  public class uploadfile
  {
    public void ReadFile(string file, string companycode)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        string str;
        int rCnt = 0;
        int cCnt = 0;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application(); //<==Crashes right here

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
       //Code eliminated for brevity
     }
  }
}
```

I get error 0x80040154, "Class not registered", each time I run this code. I have tried targeting X86 and reinstalled Office on my PC. I have search the internet but in most sources, it is a problem after it is installed on someone's machine, but it is happening to me in VS2010.

Comment: Do you have installed Microsoft Office XXXX Primary Interop Assemblies for your version of office?

Comment: @pistipanko I have installed the msi

Comment: What version of Excel do you have installed (and which version of the interop are you using... that is, what do you select when you do 'Add Reference')?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Home Office and Student 2010 and 14.0.0.0

Comment: It could be a version conflict of Office PIAs and reference to Office Interop in your project.

Comment: @Joe - ok, how about the bitness, what are the versions of Office, Windows, and the application (32 or 64 bit)?

Comment: Yes, don't expect a "Home and Student" edition to support interop.  Ask at superuser.com to be sure.

Comment: @Joe - This might also be helpful if is not a bit issue ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052678/excel-interop-works-on-machine-with-office-2007-but-fails-on-machine-with-office)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the correct version of Office. Switched to using CSV instead of xlsx.